# Issue with imports in React/Redux application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, import, export

I'm using a Rails-style organization for a React/Redux project but I'm having an import issue that I can't figure out.

I have a `constants` directory with a module index (index.js) that looks like this:

```
import * as types from './ActionTypes';

export default types;
```

(All my action creators are in `./ActionTypes`.)

I then have an `actions/index.js` file where I import all the constants I need for my actions (I've included just one of the action creators for brevity):

```
import * as c from './../constants';

...

export const toggleForm = () => ({
  type: c.TOGGLE_FORM
});
```

I've thoroughly tested all reducers and action creators - and all tests pass without import issues.

However, in my React app, which was working before I refactored to use action creators, I get the following issue and my project won't compile: `Attempted import error: 'TOGGLE_FORM' is not exported from './../constants' (imported as 'c').`

If I specify that constants should be imported into `actions/index.js` with `import * as c from './../constants/ActionTypes.js';` (bypassing my constant's directory's module index) - the React application compiles correctly but the tests for my action creators breaks.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
import * as types from './ActionTypes';

export default types;
```

and instead export all your actions as const like so

```
// user authentication actions
export const SET_USER = 'SET_USER'
export const CLEAR_USER = 'CLEAR_USER'
export const VERIFY_USER = 'VERIFY_USER'
```

it should work now